# Adding an alert video for rewarded video ads

Tags: ios, xcode, button, video, show

I have an iOS app with a button that (when tapped) plays rewarded video ads one after the other. The first times its tapped it plays ads from ad network 1, the second time its tapped it plays ads from ad network 2, and so on.

I want to add an alert that appears when the button is tapped asking the user if he/she are sure they want to play the video - if yes then the video plays, if no then the alert disappears.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
- (IBAction)freeTenCoins:(id)sender
```

{

```
// Try AppLovin.
if ([ALIncentivizedInterstitialAd isReadyForDisplay]) {
    NSLog(@"Trying AppLovin");
    [ALIncentivizedInterstitialAd show];
    [Coins instance].coins += 10;

// Try LeadBolt.
} else {
    NSLog(@"Trying LeadBolt");
    [AppTracker loadModule:@"video" viewController:self];
}
```

Can anyone here show me how to show this alert? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the AppLovin SDK has this feature built in.

All you need to do is go to the [Manage Applications](https://www.applovin.com/manage) page, scroll down to the Rewarded Section and turn "Pre-video Modal" to on. We'll show an alert asking if they'd like to view the video, and then act on that. If they choose yes, we'll show an ad on your behalf; if they choose no, we'll notify you via the optional delegate method `userDeclinedToViewAd:` in `ALAdRewardDelegate`.

[image: Turning on Pre Video modal screenshot]

Of course you can also implement this feature yourself using `UIAlertController` or `UIAlertView`. This is actually what we do internally in the SDK anyway. [This question elaborates more on that subject.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491724/detecting-button-click-with-uialertview)