# How do I get iOS system alertView callback?

Tags: ios, callback, system, alertview

[image: I want to get this alertView callback]

1. This alertView pop up from system;
2. I want to know when the user click "Cancel", and when the user click "Pair".

   I know AppDelegate.m->`applicationDidBecomeActive:` will be executed, but I don't know the user click "Cancel" or "Pair".

Anyone give some help? Thanks.

Comment: There is no direct indication of whether they clicked cancel or pair; If they clicked pair and completed pairing then you should get Bluetooth data.  If they clicked cancel then you will be unable to read the Bluetooth attributes with encryption required

Comment: Means you want to detect the action of user on click of Pair and Cancel button.

Comment: This link my help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491724/detecting-button-click-with-uialertview